# SilverStripe Translatable save value in default locale, and duplicate it to non-default locales

Tags: php, translation, silverstripe

I have my project built with `SilverStripe` 3.1.13 (both CMS and Framework), and I'm using `silverstripe-translatable` and `dataobject-translatable` in order to organize my translations on the website.

Let's say I have `Post.php` (which is `DataObject` for working with Posts on my website), and each post got it own `category` (`many-many` relationship goes here, but it doesn't really matter)).

The problem is: I hit `Save` button when creating new `Post` dataobject and I want to these `category`'ies would be duplicated automatically to another locales.

How could I implement that in my app? I want to save these values (they're boolean) into another translations of these dataobjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is afaik no built in functionality but you can write something like this in the onAfterWrite() method:

```
public function onAfterWrite() {
    $this->syncCategories();
}

public function syncCategories() {
    //check if you're in main language, assuminig en_US here
    if ($this->Locale !== 'en_US') return;
    foreach ($this->getTranslations() as $translatedPage) {
        //sync relations here
        $translatedPage->RelationName = $this->RelationName;
        //maybe more fine grained locic for only publishing when translated page is alredy published
        $translatedPage->doPublish(); //writes and publishes in one
    }
}
```

Comment: updating a $many_many relation you need to take care of items added and items removed, but you won't need to publish the page again.